# From where can i download the iPhone WebApp?

Tags: iphone, sdk

if i have submitted the iphone WebApp at

https://adcweb.apple.com/iphone/index.php

using ADC Account.

i want to know where can i get iPhone WebApp ?

is it from iTunes or from my WebServer.

Thanks in advace...

Comment: is it need to download in iPhone or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Safari and browse to your App.  You can use the "+" at the bottom of the screen to add your App to your home screen.

Comment: "Adding App to my home screen" means making it as default Home page in mobile safari ?

reply please...